# Is the Java Builder pattern (Bloch) really related to the GOF builder?

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

Joshua Bloch suggests the builder pattern as a solution for a class with too many construction options , or too many constructor arguments.

The GOF builder basically intends to "separate the construction of an object from its representation", or basically to create an abstract construction algorithm for different final products with the same base class.

It seems to me that other than both being creational patterns, these two are not only not the same pattern, but not even closely related.

Is Bloch's Java Builder really the same kind of builder?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only thing that is different is that in the GOF Builder pattern they don't use the fluent idiom. But the aim and purpose of the two is the same: to avoid telescoping constructors by separating the build logic from the final object representation.

Answer (score 1):

I think, yes. Bloch's example does not have an explicit Director class. In his example the class in where you are building is the Director. In some other class you will be building in some other way that'll be another Director. In GOF the Director is more for clarity. However you build you are getting an object of the same interface (or subclassing the same base class).

Comment: Come to think about it, a consequence of the implicit director approach is another difference: you can easily create a builder using an existing object as a prototype. With an explicit director, you'd have to expose the entire internal state of the object to do so.